# Como guardar en el LocalStorage este componente. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Buenas tardes, Me gustarias guardar este componente  en el localStorage claro esta con toda su informacion pintada, intente
guardarla con: localStorage.setItem("accessToken", JSON.stringify( data.data )), me la guarda pero se pierde el componente no se como hacer.

```
const onClickModal = (item) => {
    const exists = carrito.filter(i => i.product_id === item.product_id).length > 0
    if (!exists) {
        saveCarrito(carrito.concat({...item, quantity: 1, data}))
        setData([])
    } 
}

const modifyQuantity = (product_id, qty) => {
    const newCart = carrito.map(i => {
        if (i.product_id === product_id) {
            return { ...i, quantity: i.quantity + qty }
        }
        return i;
    })
    const cartWithoutZeros = newCart.filter(i => i.quantity !== 0)
    saveCarrito(cartWithoutZeros)
}
```

Cada ves que hago un onlClick filtro primero que exista esa orden para que no la pinte luego la mando al Hook de carrito y la concateno con el parametro quantity, para modificarlo con la otra funcion que esta ahi, quisiera saber como hacer persistir esos componentes iterados, aqui esta cuando los pinto

```
const itemsCarro = carrito.map((itemcarrito) => {
    return (
        <ItemCarro
            key={itemcarrito.product_id}
            item={itemcarrito}
            modifyQuantity={modifyQuantity}
            carrito={carrito} 
        />
    )
})
```

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, puedo recomendarte el hook **Context** que tiene React, te permitirá persistir los datos en un estado o contexto a través de todos tus componentes, y es muy simple de utilizar: [Context](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)
Lo bueno es que puedes retornar objetos en el contexto para cambiar el estado y así tu componente se podría renderizar nuevamente. Si requires mas ayuda con la implementación de este **hook** aquí estamos para ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo veré si lo puedo implementar y te comento que resulta muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que con `return { ...i, quantity: i.quantity + qty }` devuelves el elemento modificado, pero no devuelves nada cuando no se cumple la condición. Modifica solo la cantidad cuando se cumpla la condición y **siempre** devuelve el elemento:

```
const modifyQuantity = (product_id, qty) => {
    const newCart = carrito.map(i => {
        if (i.product_id === product_id) {
            // Incrementas la cantidad
            i.quantity += qty;
        }
        // Devuelves el elemento
        return i;
    })
    const cartWithoutZeros = newCart.filter(i => i.quantity !== 0)
    saveCarrito(cartWithoutZeros)
}
```

Con tu código actual, solo agregando el `return i;` se soluciona:

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 1, qty:3 },
    {id: 2, qty:3 },
    {id: 3, qty:3 },
    {id: 4, qty:3 },
];
function sumar(id, qty) {
    const newArr = arr.map(i => {
        if(i.id == id) {
            return {...i, qty: i.qty + qty };
        }
        // Te falta este return
        return i;
    });
    return newArr;
}

console.log(sumar(2, 2));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo revisaré y te comento a ver cómo me va, muchas gracias 